# using 5 jquery files in one jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp, slider

i m building a project of online shopping site in which i am using a template which provides 3 jquery files for 2 sliders in it and i have put 2 more jquery files in it for price slider but when i load the webpage which includes all 3 sliders it works only for price slider not other 2 but when i comment that slider jquery file then other 2 slider works plzz tell me how to resolve...
jquery files for 2 image sliders are:-

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-func.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

jquery files for price range slider are::-

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are including two different version of jQuery in your project... drop the older one (or preferably update to 1.11.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different versions of jQuery included with these lines:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
```

They will clash. There are ways to support multiple versions of jQuery in one project, but that is usually a fallback when you have legacy code you cannot update.

Your best bet is to use the later version only, so your script includes will look like:

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script> 
 <script src="js/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-func.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Make sure you include jQuery first, then jQuery UI, then the rest of the scripts.

I also suggest you update to the latest *HTML4 compatible* version of jQuery if you can (version 1.11.1) and update to the latest matching jQuery UI version.

Answer (score 0):

One way to acheive this is to `relinquish '$' variable`.

> **[jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)**
>
> A Boolean indicating whether to remove all jQuery variables from the
>   global scope (including jQuery itself).

If you need to use another JavaScript library or another jQuery-version alongside original jQuery, return control of $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict().

*Old references of $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores them*.

Example snippet:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script>
   jq162 = jQuery.noConflict( true );//This restores 1.10.2 to '$'
   jq162('body').show();//jq162 holds jQuery 1.6.2
</script>
```